# Selecting element of first child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that looks like this:

```
$(".container").on("click", ".comment:first-child > .like_btn", function () {
    console.log("it works!");
});
```

The `.comment` in the `.container` get dynamically added. What I'd like to do is detect if there was a click on the like button of the first comment. However, what I have right now doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment"> //Dynamically added
     <div class="like_btn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: There are no errors, just that the click event doesn't fire.

Comment: any error??????

Comment: Attach it to the document instead: `$(document).on("click", ".container .comment:first-child > .like_btn", function () {`

Comment: @PranavCBalan No error, just that the click event doesn't fire. If I made it just like this ".comment:first-child" and removed `> .like_btn`then it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try attaching your handler to the `document` instead:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".container .comment:first-child > .like_btn", function() {
    console.log("it works!");
});

setTimeout(() => $(".comment").append("<div class='like_btn'>Like!</div>"), 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment"> //Dynamically added
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use event delegation on the `document` element, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".container").append(
      `<div class="comment">
         <div class="like_btn">LIKE 1</div>
       </div>
       <div class="comment">
         <div class="like_btn">LIKE 2</div>
       </div>`
    );
});

$(document).on("click", ".container .comment:first-child > .like_btn", function()
{
    console.log("it works!");
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

However, if the `.container` element is not added, also, dynamically, then your code should work fine as shown on next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".container").append(
      `<div class="comment">
         <div class="like_btn">LIKE 1</div>
       </div>
       <div class="comment">
         <div class="like_btn">LIKE 2</div>
       </div>`
    );
});

$(".container").on("click", ".comment:first-child > .like_btn", function()
{
    console.log("it works!");
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".container").append(
      `<div class="comment">
         <div class="like_btn">LIKE 1</div>
       </div>
       <div class="comment">
         <div class="like_btn">LIKE 2</div>
       </div>`
    );
});

$(document).on("click", ".container div:first-of-type > .like_btn", function()
{
    console.log("it works!");
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: If comment class is rendered dynamically still <div> will be same in the dynamic rendered element.

Answer (score -1):

try removing the '>'

```
$('.container .comment .like-btn').on('click', function(){ //do something })
```

Comment: This will only add it to items that already exist on the page.